# ReadMemory value not updated correctly

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

I'm having an issue in Reading another process memory I'm doing this in C#.

I have a loop that go through data and write it into console (for now)

```
public bool UpdateData()
{
dataReceived = RPM.Read<Data>(0x5456875);
return true;
}

While (true)
if(UpdateData)
{
Console.WriteLine(dataReceived.ValueUpdated)
}
```

I simplified the code for the purpose of the question.

The update function is processing in 0.005 ms.

The data change everytime and very fast. So my dataReceived should change too, but it does it with delay (0.5s) so I have numerous time the same output but it should change everytime.

I know C# is not the best allies here, but as it takes 0.005ms it should work doesn't it ?
What could be the issue here ?

Thanks.

Comment: `UpdateData` always returns `true`. That looks odd. The rest of you code an explanation I cannot understand.

Comment: I simplified the code so I could be simple to read here.

It doesn't always return true, but the fact is the delay on displaying that value it reads.